# need help in writing pivot query to select columns from different select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012, i need help in getting the following output. My table structure is as follows:

```
declare @TestTable table (MaterialCode char(5), ItemCode char(5), ItemName varchar(50))

insert into @TestTable values ('AA-01', 'A0001', 'iPhone')
insert into @TestTable values ('AA-02', 'A0001', 'iPad')
insert into @TestTable values ('AA-03', 'A0001', 'iPod')

insert into @TestTable values ('AA-01', 'B0001', 'Galaxy Tab')
insert into @TestTable values ('AA-02', 'B0001', 'Galaxy Note')

insert into @TestTable values ('AA-01', 'C0001', 'Nokia Lumnia')
insert into @TestTable values ('AA-02', 'C0001', 'Motorola')
insert into @TestTable values ('AA-03', 'C0001', 'Samsung S3')
insert into @TestTable values ('AA-04', 'C0001', 'Sony')

--select * from @TestTable

select MaterialCode, ItemCode as [A_ItemCode], ItemName as [A_ItemName] 
from @TestTable where ItemCode='A0001'

select MaterialCode, ItemCode as [B_ItemCode], ItemName as [B_ItemName] 
from @TestTable where ItemCode='B0001'

select MaterialCode, ItemCode as [C_ItemCode], ItemName as [C_ItemName] 
from @TestTable where ItemCode='C0001'
```

And the output i need should produced from the above three select statements, which should be as follows:

[image]

As you can see, when there is no record, NULLs are displayed there. Can anyone help me getting this output. TIA.

**EDIT**

@JohnLBevan, I tried your pivot approach and when I have another record which is has ItemCode = D0001

```
insert into @TestTable values ('AA-05', 'D0001', 'Test1')
```

now even that record is being displayed as

```
AA-05   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

How to avoid these type of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using a pivot, but this gives you the desired results:

```
SELECT coalesce(a.MaterialCode, b.MaterialCode, c.MaterialCode) MaterialCode 
, a.ItemCode A_ItemCode
, a.ItemName A_ItemName
, b.ItemCode B_ItemCode
, b.ItemName B_ItemName
, c.ItemCode C_ItemCode
, c.ItemName C_ItemName
FROM (select * from @TestTable where ItemCode='A0001') a
full outer join (select * from @TestTable where ItemCode='B0001') b
    on a.MaterialCode = b.MaterialCode
full outer join (select * from @TestTable where ItemCode='C0001') c
    on a.MaterialCode = c.MaterialCode
    or b.MaterialCode = c.MaterialCode
```

Here's an alternate which uses a pivot, though this feels messier:

```
SELECT MaterialCode
, case when [A0001] is null then null else 'A0001' end A_ItemCode
, [A0001] A_ItemName
, case when [A0001] is null then null else 'B0001' end B_ItemCode
, [B0001] B_ItemName
, case when [A0001] is null then null else 'C0001' end C_ItemCode
, [C0001] C_ItemName
FROM @TestTable a
pivot (
    max(ItemName) 
    for ItemCode in ([A0001],[B0001],[C0001])
) pvt
```

**EDIT**

If you want something a little more flexible, here's a dynamic version:

```
declare @dynamicSql nvarchar(max)
, @dynamicSqlPart nvarchar(max)

select * into #TestTable from @TestTable

set @dynamicSql = 'SELECT MaterialCode ' + CHAR(10)
select @dynamicSql = @dynamicSql + ', case when [' + ItemCode + '] is null then null else ''' + ItemCode + ''' end ' + ItemCode + '_ItemCode ' + CHAR(10)
    + ', ' + QUOTENAME(ItemCode) + ' ' + ItemCode + '_ItemName ' + CHAR(10)
, @dynamicSqlPart = ISNULL(@dynamicSqlPart + ',','') +  QUOTENAME(ItemCode)
from (select distinct ItemCode from @TestTable) x

set @dynamicSql = @dynamicSql + 'from #TestTable a' + CHAR(10)
    + 'pivot (' + CHAR(10)
    + ' max(ItemName) ' + CHAR(10)
    + ' for ItemCode in (' + @dynamicSqlPart + ')' + CHAR(10)
    + ') pvt' + CHAR(10)

print isnull(@dynamicSql,'?')
exec (@dynamicSql)

drop table #TestTable
```

Comment: +1 Here is a live demo: [**Live Demo**](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/84455)

Comment: Ooh; I didn't know stack exchange had that feature; nice.  Thanks @MahmoudGamal.

Comment: You can query all data of the stackoverflow.com and other stackexchange sites as well. But there is another site better than it for sql demos: [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) .

Comment: ps. despite my comments above on the pivot table not looking as neat, I just looked at the execution plan and the pivot is much more efficient.

Comment: @JohnLBevan, thats perfect man. I didnt even think about using full outer join. actually im new to pivot so i cant say anything about your second query. thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries - I've also stuck up a dynamic version should that be of interest (i.e. if you potentially have to deal with more than just 3 item codes at runtime).  Useful resources on PIVOTs here if you want to read up: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/tag/pivot/ & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @JohnLBevan, wow... thats just amazing, i didnt know queries can be written in this way.

Comment: No worries - if you're using the **last (dynamic) method** you will get an additional row, but with two extra columns on the end.  Using the **first (outer join) method** you'll get the same results as before you had D0001.  Using the **second (pivot) method** you'd need to update the `FROM @TestTable a` line to `FROM (select * from @TestTable where ItemCode in ('A0001','B0001','C0001')) a`.  Alternatively if you want to update the **first/second** queries to include columns for D0001 just copy the pattern used for A,B & C.

Comment: @JohnLBevan, im using second pivot method and this solved the problem. thank you.